# MapRoute to remove action from url for single action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

So I've read a bunch of answer, but I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong. Here's the route I am using

```
     routes.MapRoute("project",
           "project/{id}/{slug}",
           new { controller = "project", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, slug = "" }
        );
      routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This works, but it's making all of the other actions in the book controller redirect to the index action. I don't want that, I only want to make my urls look like  http://www.example.com/project/1/awesome-book, which works, but all the other action I'm using, from that page via Ajax, get pointed to the index action instead of their correct actions.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an integer constraint for id parameter.

```
 routes.MapRoute("project",
       "project/{id}/{slug}",
       new { controller = "project", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, slug = "" },
       new { id = @"\d+"});
```

This route has a constraint on id parameter. It is a simple regex that checks if id parameter is an integer. Since this route is above the default route, it will be checked first. 
http://www.example.com/project/1/awesome-book will be mapped to Index action. But when you try to reach other actions, your second segment will contain an action name. Since an action name won't be an integer, the request will be resolved by the default route.

Comment: Anything matching `project/something/something` was being sent to the first route, attempting to interpret the first something as `id` and the second as `slug`. Telling it that `id` has to be an integer means that it can tell that `project/action/id` doesn't use this route because `action` isn't an integer.